# Media plugin is not working in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, jquery-plugins, media

i am trying to use media plugin in cake php but i coulnt get it, it shows error:

```
 Warning (2): Missing argument 2 for MediasController::index() [APP\Plugin\Media\Controller\MediasController.php, line 26]
Notice (8): Undefined variable: ref_id [APP\Plugin\Media\Controller\MediasController.php, line 27]
```

can any one say what might be the problem

Comment: How about reading the error message? It already tells you very exactly what and where is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly says you are missing the second argument and ref_id is not defined. Take a look at your code.

print_r everything to see if the value is set.